# MS Access- form value filled automatically by combo box (how to insert into table)

Tags: ms-access, invoice

I have a form that has sub-form on it. On the sub-form, there is a field (price) which value is automatically filled from a combo box (product) and from a table (products). All this happens on the form. How can I pass the value (price) to the a table named "invoices"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be as simple as this.

```
Dim strSQL as string
strSQL = "INSERT INTO YourTable ([Account Number], [Dollar Amount]) VALUES (" & Me.cboAccount & ", " & nz( me.txtDollars,0) & ")"
Currentdb.execute strsql, dbfailonerror
```

Modify to suit your needs.

Here is another, more embellished, solution.

[MS Access: Insert a selected entry from Combo Box into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887048/ms-access-insert-a-selected-entry-from-combo-box-into-table)