# How can I avoid duplicate records with autonumber ID and how to increment autonumber ID sequentially in access?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, duplicates, autonumber

I have an input table (including input ID and Input fields) and a type table (including typeID and type fields) where there is one to many relationship between them (one type ID to many inputs)... InputID and typeID are the primary keys and autonumbers. I have a data entry form where the user can select input from a combo box and then the correspodning type from another combo box. Every time I enter a new input and select a type ( from the existing types in the type combo box), I have a duplicated type in the type table as typeID is an autonumber (duplicate types). My first question is that how can I avoid generating duplicated records for type when user chooses from one of those existing types by keeping the typeID as an autonumber?

another question is that why autonumber filed doesn't increase sequentially when I add a new record from the form to the table? for example even if I had deleted some records seems like it has those IDs in the memory and increment from there not from the last existing ID in the table. I was trying to use compact and repair option but didn't work.

I aprpeciate your time and help in advance.

Comment: to broad to answer, but to get you started you need a normalized table structure including the relationship between tables.  For a one input-type to many inputs add a foreign key(typeid) to the input table.  Then hit relationships on the ribbon and tell access about the relationship.  Once you see the line between typeid in both tables access knows about the relationship.  Next select the inputs table and hit create form on the ribbon.  Access will create a data entry/search form.  Play around to get a feel then make the form pretty and try making the form from the other table.

Comment: Thanks, I did all these things. One-to-many relationship is set and I designed a form including inputID, input, typeID and type for data entry. My form is working fine. Just not sure why everytime I enter a new input with a specific type from the combo list of type, it adds a duplicated type in type table. Also, ID autonumbers are not generated sequentially, it jumps from 10 to 20 for example...

Comment: One possible part of the problem is under the table design tab your table primary key's property new value is set to random rather than increment.  next what you are trying to do is to insert a value using a combobox(2) so look up examples like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887048/ms-access-insert-a-selected-entry-from-combo-box-into-table  Then make a new question or edit this one providing table structure and code so we can easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: @mazoula:  The primary key's property was set to 'increment', as I am a beginner in access, I didn't code for creating tables/form/etc. Do you need screenshots of form/table/relations...?  is there any way I can directly send you my access file? Thanks alot.

Comment: Stack overflow is only for answering questions, However there are other sites that allow for posting of files.  It would be usually be far faster to wrangle a database into shape than composing an answer but then stack overflow wouldn't be the programming manual that it is.  I would bang on it for awhile then rewrite your question with tables and forms so the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: Thanks @mazoula,  here is how I made the form/table :main form includes:  Design inputID (autonumber), Designinput (combo box), TypeID (autonumber) and type (combo box).... for generating combo boxes there is no data binding, so control source and row source of Designinput is Designinput field from input table and control/row source of type is type field from type table. Input table includes: Designinput ID (autonumber), Designinput, typeID  and type table includes : typeID(autonumber) and type. Relationship: one from typeID (in type table) to many (to typeID in Input table).

Comment: There is still too little information to replicate the problem but it seems you need the combo box to run vba in the after update event.  That means the combo box must be unbound which means the control source is not set!  I couldn't find helpful examples of inserting from combo-boxes but filtering examples abound.  Try this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_nAh_lvlZI  then replace the filter code with code to insert a record such as here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/data-access-objects/add-a-record-to-a-dao-recordset